# compilation error when using template argument list

Tags: c++, templates

i try to make simple template class but in the dtor it gives compilation error:
this is what i have :

```
#include <map>

template<class k , class v> 
class ObjectMap
{
    public:
        ObjectMap(k key, v value)
        {
            InnerObjectMap = new std::map<key, value>();
        }
        ~ObjectMap();
    private:
        std::map<k,v> *InnerObjectMap;
};
```

and here is the cpp file that has only the dtor

```
#include "ObjectMap.h"
ObjectMap::~ObjectMap()
{

}
```

put im getting the compilation error :

```
1>  ObjectMap.cpp
1>\objectmap.cpp(6): error C2955: 'ObjectMap' : use of class template requires template argument list
1>          \objectmap.h(10) : see declaration of 'ObjectMap'
1>          \objectmap.h(10) : see declaration of 'ObjectMap'
1>\objectmap.cpp(7): error C2509: '{dtor}' : member function not declared in 'ObjectMap'
1>          \objectmap.h(10) : see declaration of 'ObjectMap'
1>\objectmap.cpp(7): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

what im doing wrong here ?

Comment: You missed the `template<class k , class v>` above the definition and the template arguments `ObjectMap<k, v>::~ObjectMap()`

Comment: Thanks allot for your quick answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ObjectMap` is not just class. It's a class template.

It should be:

```
#include <map>

template <class k, class v> 
class ObjectMap
{
    public:
        ObjectMap(k key, v value)
        {
            InnerObjectMap = new std::map<key, value>();
        }
        ~ObjectMap();
    private:
        std::map<k,v> *InnerObjectMap;
};

template <class k, class v>
ObjectMap<k, v>::~ObjectMap()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Notice that the destructor is also in the class template definition file, not *.cpp file. Otherwise, the compiler won't be able to instantiate your destructor.

Comment: why is that ? do you say i can't set the destructor in its own cpp file ?

Comment: @user63898 Yes. When the compiler instantiate your destructor in another module, it doesn't know the destructor - it only knows `~ObjectMap();`, which is in the header file.

Comment: @user63898  this will help you in detail . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @Steephen Thanks. That's what I really want to link.

Comment: Thanks , but what if i have in this class also member functions that are not related to the template where should i implement them ?

Comment: @user63898 `not related to the template` the `ObjectMap` is a template. Its member *is* related to template.

Answer (score 1):

```
InnerObjectMap = new std::map<key, value>();
```

Above line of code should rewrite as follows, since `std::map` declaration expects  types instead values;

```
InnerObjectMap = new std::map<k, v>();
```

Your destructor definition should change as follows since it is a template:

```
template<class k , class v> 
ObjectMap<k,v>::~ObjectMap()
{

}
```

You can see more details on why you should implement templates in header file from this SO link : [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)